# What is the difference between ClientContainer and WSLogin?

Tags: websphere, datasource, jaas

I am using WebSphere v8.5 and in the administration console, and the **Security Settings** in the **Data Sources** section allow me to set my **mapping-configuration alias** to either **ClientContainer** or **WSLogin**. What is the difference between these two settings?

I am able to connect and my project appears to work regardless of which setting I choose. Can someone please explain when is one setting chosen over the other?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each one in the list is a Java Authentication and Authorization Service (JAAS) configuration, which in turn contains an IBM-implementation of the JAAS Login Module.

According to the reference page, [Login configuration for Java Authentication and Authorization Service](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rsec_logmod.html):

- The `WSLogin` module defines a login configuration and the LoginModule implementation that can be used by applications in general.
- The `ClientContainer` module defines a login configuration and the LoginModule implementation that is similar to the WSLogin module, but enforces the requirements of the WebSphere Application Server client container.
- The `DefaultPrincipalMapping` module defines a special LoginModule that is typically used by Java 2 Connector to map an authenticated WebSphere Application Server user identity to a set of user authentication data (user ID and password) for the specified back-end enterprise information system (EIS).

So for general use, you can use the WSLogin module. When you use a Java EE client, use the ClientContainer module. And when using Java 2 Connectors, use the DefaultPrincipalMapping module.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link for a bit more information [Configuration entry settings for Java Authentication and Authorization Service](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/usec_jaas.html)

In general, for any server resources like Datasources, queue connection factories etc, you should use DefaultPrincipalMapping.

ClientContainer alias is more dedicated to external applications running in the client container that will connect to WAS, and WSLogin is more appropriate for apps running on the server that would like to customize authentication process.